# Issue horizontally centering an element with absolute position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have searched for similar questions however unfortunatley the left:50% soultion does not work here.

I have a container (.leftLanding) with a relative postion, inside this I have a div with an absolute position (.imageCenter) which I would like to center horizontally. Adding left: 50% doesn't actually center it however as the container has a with of 85% I also tried 42.5% but this didn't work either.

I've removed all unnecessary code.

HTML:

```
<div id="landing-images">
    <div class="leftLanding left">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <div class="imageCenter">
            Test
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="rightLanding right">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <div class="imageCenter">
            Test
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="leftLanding left">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <div class="imageCenter">
            Test
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftLanding {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.imageCenter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 30%;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Center it inside the `<div class="leftLanding">` element?

Comment: @LGSon I tried using align-items center in the leftLanding but I also have another div inside there which gets centered vertically which unfortunatley isn't where I want it

Comment: I colored the other div light blue in my answer, and how should that position itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this rule, where `flex: 1` tells the flex items (in this case the first `div` and the last `img`) to take all the available space (and since they are 2 they share it 50/50)

```
.leftLanding div:first-child,
.leftLanding img{
    flex: 1;
}
```

And the use `left: 50%, transform: translate(-50%)` like this it will work

```
.imageCenter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 30%;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

*Added borders on the two so it clearly shows*

```css
.leftLanding {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.leftLanding div:first-child,
.leftLanding img{
    flex: 1;
}

.leftLanding div:first-child {
    background: lightblue;
}

.imageCenter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 30%;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="landing-images">
    <div class="leftLanding left">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <div class="imageCenter">
            Test
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="http://placehold.it/150/f00">
    </div>
    <div class="rightLanding right">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <div class="imageCenter">
            Test
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="http://placehold.it/150/f00">
    </div>
    <div class="leftLanding left">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <div class="imageCenter">
            Test
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="http://placehold.it/150/f00">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @LGSon to make it clearer this is what I was attempting to do https://gyazo.com/6b105edf8b5c91c33366d22b9ae44867 Would you mind explaining to me the first rule you added, i've not seen it before. I tried the transform method alone without it before posting and it wasn't successfull.

Comment: @EthanBristow Updated my answer, is that explanation okay?

Comment: Kind of makes sense, thank you. But what is the flex: 1; doing?

Comment: @EthanBristow `flex: 1` tells the flex items (in this case the first `div` and the last `img`) to take all the available space (and since they are 2 they share it 50/50)

Comment: I do have another div inside with a 0px height which doesn't appear until the container is hovered over, would this cause problems in the future?

Comment: @EthanBristow It depends on how it is positioned. Make a fiddle with that extra div, its hover rule and a short explanation, and I help you make it work

Comment: This has worked perfectly so far so hopefully it's ok but here's the fiddle, it's slightly buggy becuase a few global css rules are missing https://jsfiddle.net/dzd368tz/

Comment: @EthanBristow It appear to work...let me know down the road if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

To center an absolutely positioned element horizontally, use a combination of `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` and it will center it relative to it's closest non-`static` positioned ancestor.

Though I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this layout, so not sure if that's really what you're looking for, but added some borders/background colors to show the children are centered horizontally.

> I have a container (.leftLanding) with a relative postion, inside this I have a div with an absolute position (.imageCenter) which I would like to center horizontally.

This will center `.imageCenter` in `.leftLanding`.

```css
.leftLanding {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.imageCenter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 30%;
  align-self: center;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="landing-images">
  <div class="leftLanding left">
    <div class="imageCover">
    </div>
    <div class="imageCenter">
      Test
    </div>
    <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="rightLanding right">
    <div class="imageCover">
    </div>
    <div class="imageCenter">
      Test
    </div>
    <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG3.png">
  </div>
  <div class="leftLanding left">
    <div class="imageCover">
    </div>
    <div class="imageCenter">
      Test
    </div>
    <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG2.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `.imageCenter` to `width:100%` and style `display:block` `margin:auto` to the `img` tag

```
.imageCenter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```